# Median into JMeter report

Tags: jmeter

I execute my JMeter performance test from commandline, and generate the report afterwards.

```
jmeter -n -t <jmx file> -l <log file>
jmeter -g <log file> -o <report loc>
```

I realized that the generated report doesn't contain median (however aggregated result on the frontend contains it).
Are there any way to provide median value into report generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Overview](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview):

> A Statistics table providing in one table a summary of all metrics per transaction including 3 configurable percentiles :

and into [General Settings](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general)

> Percentiles used by Summary table and Percentile graphs can be adjusted to different values by using the 3 properties:
>
> - aggregate_rpt_pct1 : Defaults to 90
> - aggregate_rpt_pct2 : Defaults to 95
> - aggregate_rpt_pct3 : Defaults to 99

So you can switch any of these pre-configured percentiles into the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) (which is also known as  2nd quartile, 5th decile, or 50th percentile)

So if you add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=50
```

then next time you generate the dashboard you will see median values in the first percentile column (same applies to i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener)

you can also pass the value via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jaggregate_rpt_pct1=50 <log file> -o <report log>
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)